# Add custom cursor to CSS stylesheet via JS prompt

Tags: html, javascript, css

I'm trying to make a custom cursor setter. You can customize cursors in CSS, so I went there first.

```css
html {
cursor: url(MY URL GOES HERE), auto !important;
}
```

It works at this point. However, I want the average user to be able to enter an image URL and see the cursor change to that. I decided to use JavaScript to do that.

```js
function customCursor() {
var v1 = prompt("Enter the image URL you want to be your mouse cursor.");
var style = document.createElement('style'); 
style.innerHTML = `html {cursor:url(` + v1 + `);  }  `; 
document.head.appendChild(style);
}
```

However, it doesn't work. I checked the current page HTML with Firebug, and the  tag *is* added. And when I use JavaScript to add it manually, it works. So why would it not work?

I also made sure to keep the images I chose below 128x128.

Comment: I suppose it doesn't work because the cursor you previously manually set has `!important`. Then if the css is properly added into the `head` it can't win because the other declaration has a greater css specificity. Try to remove !important (or add it also in  the style injected)

Answer (score -1):

After massive changes to the code, it still is not working. However, I now understand a reason why (by using devtools to read what was actually being added):
*Instead of dynamically using my variable, it was treating the variable name as the URL itself. This makes this question mostly irrelevant.*

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/937900)